# Python "module not found" or "relative path with no parent" or "no module named <app>" inconsistent errors

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, wsl-2

I spent 6 hours trying to solve an importing problem that looked like this:

Directory:

```
workspace
workspace/src
workspace/src/app/main.py
workspace/src/app/__init__.py
workspace/src/app/api/api_v1.py
workspace/src/app/api/__init__.py
```

main.py

```
from app.api.api_v1 import api_router
```

api.py

```
from fastapi import APIRouter
api_router = APIRouter()
```

Errors when trying to run main.py:

1. from app.api.api_v1 import api_router > app module not found
2. from .api.api_v1 import api_router > relative import but no parent module
3. from api.api_v1 import api_router > this works but linting doesn't work

I then add extra paths to .vscode settings:

```
{
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["./src/app"]
}
```

I was running WSL2 on windows with the files on a mounted drive, but moved it to a home drive on the linux WSL remote thing: /mnt/c/james > /home/james/ ~$

My question is how come I run main.py and it gave error 1, then literally running it again right away gives error 2? Then adding extra paths doesn't make a difference and then the next morning I restarted my laptop and everything magically worked?

I want to cry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems that the answer might be that I need to change the directory I am running the the main.py from in terminal:

this don't work:

```
~workspace/$ main.py
```

this works:

```
~workspace/$ cd src/
~workspace/src/$ main.py
```

Comment: Another thing I've been doing is comment out, save or uncomment out and save the .vscode settings that gives python extra paths routes. This forces vscode to re-asses all the packages again. Works well.